# How can I detect when shift key is pressed in C?

Tags: c, macos

Im using GCC compiler and I want to write a program that waits for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to be pressed...

I can detect <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> but I can't find out that <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is pressed or not.

please write the code compeletly!

Comment: What platform are you programming for?

Comment: Catch the shift ascii key code? I'm assuming that you're catching the other key codes in a similar manner.

Comment: By *platform* Jerry means Linux, Windows, Mac ...

Comment: @JamieTaylor Shift doesn't have an ascii code. Nor does Control.

Comment: @Chris Ah, yes. Momentary slip of the mind. Sorry

Comment: The program is console-based or window-based? Are you using any framework or library?

Comment: @JamieTaylor but Control+A has an ascii code

Comment: @Lohoris It's Console-based,I'm using mac terminal to run my program.

Comment: To the close votes. Yes the question contains a misunderstanding - but it's not a bad question, just a new programmer.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a function of the language it depends on the machine. Remember C was designed to also run on machines without a keyboard.

Detecting key presses, as with detecting mouse movement, is the job of the operating system / GUI windows you are using. It will be documented somewhere in the MacOSX documentation.

The reason you can detect ctrl-A is that there are a few ASCII codes that don't have keys and were used for control functions (ring a bell, advance paper, etc) and these are entered on a modern keyboard with ctr+letter. So it's a bit of historical accident that you can do 'ctrl'

Comment: Thanks, but what should I do now?! :D

Comment: @NimaAhmadi if this is on the console and since OSX is basically unix, use the curses lib - see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getch.3x.html